# NSDictionary parsing howto

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSDictionary that when printed looks like this

```
(
        {
        "current_game" = 1;
        "fb_id" = 1;
        "game_status" = 1;
    },
        {
        "current_game" = 4;
        "fb_id" = 2;
        "game_status" = 1;
    },
        {
        "current_game" = "";
        "fb_id" = 3;
        "game_status" = "";
    },
        {
        "current_game" = "";
        "fb_id" = 4;
        "game_status" = "";\
    }
)
```

When I loop it like

```
for (int i=0; i < [responseDict count]; i++) {  
}
```

How can I access fb_id = 1 for example?
objectAtIndex:i doesn't seem to exist and there is no key there either.

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: Please format your code, it's easy.

Comment: Fixed that for you. With a 473 rep, you should really know how to format your posts.

Comment: That looks more like an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I figured out how to do it.

So for the looping use this instead

```
for (iNSDictionary *status in responseDict) {  
}
```

That way then you can use [status objectForKey:@"fb_id"] to access.

Thanks,
Tee